# Display Average Billing Amount For Each Customer only between years 2019-2021

Tags: sql

QUESTION : Display Average Billing Amount For Each Customer ONLY between YEAR(2019-2021).
If customer doesn't have any billing amount for any of the particular year then consider as 0.

```
-------: OUTPUT :
Customer_ID |   Customer_Name   |   AVG_Billed_Amount
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           |               A               |               87.00
2           |               B               |               200.00
3           |               C               |               183.00
```

--------: EXPLANATION :
If any customer doesn't have any billing records for these 3 years then we need to consider as one record with billing_amount = 0
Like Customer  C doesn't have any record for Year 2020, so for C Average will be
(250+300+0)/3 = 183.33 OR 183.00

TEMP TABLE HAS FOLLOWING DATA

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP; 
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
      Customer_ID           INT
    , Customer_Name     NVARCHAR(100)
    , Billing_ID                NVARCHAR(100)
    , Billing_creation_Date     DATETIME
    , Billed_Amount     INT
);
INSERT INTO #TEMP 
SELECT 1, 'A', 'ID1', TRY_CAST('10-10-2020' AS DATETIME),   100 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A', 'ID2', TRY_CAST('11-11-2020' AS DATETIME),   150 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A', 'ID3', TRY_CAST('12-11-2021' AS DATETIME),   100 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', 'ID4', TRY_CAST('10-11-2019' AS DATETIME),   150 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', 'ID5', TRY_CAST('11-11-2020' AS DATETIME),   200 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', 'ID6', TRY_CAST('12-11-2021' AS DATETIME),   250 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C', 'ID7', TRY_CAST('01-01-2018' AS DATETIME),   100 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C', 'ID8', TRY_CAST('05-01-2019' AS DATETIME),   250 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C', 'ID9', TRY_CAST('06-01-2021' AS DATETIME),   300


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here, 'A' has 3 transactions - TWICE in year 2020(100+150) and 1 in year 2021(100), but none in 2019(SO, Billed_Amount= 0).
so the average will be calculated as (100+150+100+0)/4

```
DECLARE @BILL_dATE DATE = (SELECT Billing_creation_date from #temp group by customer_id, Billing_creation_date) /*-- THIS THROWS ERROR AS @BILL_DATE WON'T ACCEPT MULTIPLE VALUES.*/
```

OUTPUT should look like this:

| Customer_ID | Customer_Name | AVG_Billed_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 87.00 |
| 2 | B | 200.00 |
| 3 | C | 183.00 |

Comment: Which database do you really use? MySQL? MS SQL Server? Oracle (that's what PL/SQL tag suggests)? I don't think you use all of them. Could you fix tags, then?

Comment: I need to execute and show in multiple DB's. It includes SQL SERVER, MYSQL

Comment: The problem with that is that every RDBMS has different a different dialect, so you will likely need a different solution for each. Focus on one product and then translate to a different dialect as needed. Which are you focusing on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a formula to count the number of missing years.

- That's `3 - COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(Billing_creation_Date)`

Then the average = `SUM() / (COUNT() + (3 - COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR)))`...

```
SELECT
  Customer_ID,
  Customer_Name,
  SUM(Billed_Amount) * 1.0
  /
  (COUNT(*) + 3 - COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(Billing_creation_Date)))
    AS AVG_Billed_amount
FROM
  #temp
WHERE
      Billing_creation_Date >= '2019-01-01'
  AND Billing_creation_Date <  '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY
  Customer_ID,
  Customer_Name
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/ILcfiGWL

***Note:*** The `WHERE` clause in another answer here would cause a scan of the table, due to hiding the filtered column behind a function.  The way I've formed the `WHERE` clause allows a "Range Seek" if the column is in an index.

Comment: @pmishra Please don't send comments to me on other people's answers. Please edit your question to include an example that doesn't work. (if that example is materially different to the current question, open a new question instead)

Comment: @pmishra As explained in the answer, you want to know how many ***YEARS*** had no transactions. There should be 3 years with transactions, so that's `3 - "actual number of years with transactions"`. You add that number to count(*) and you get the divisor you're looking for. If the are 3 years with transactions; 3-3=0, so `avg=sum/count`. If there are 2 years with transactions; 3-2=1 so `avg=sum/(count+1)`. If there are 1 years with transactions; 3-1=2, so `avg=sum/(count+2)`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a query that can do that :

```
select s.Customer_ID, s.Customer_Name, sum(Billed_amount)/ ( 6 - count(1)) as AVG_Billed_Amount from (
    select Customer_ID, Customer_Name, sum(Billed_Amount) as Billed_amount
    from TEMP
    where year(Billing_creation_Date) between 2019 and 2021
    group by Customer_ID, year(Billing_creation_Date)
) as s
group by Customer_ID;
```

According to your description the customer_name C will be 137.5000 not 183.00 since 2018 is not counted and 2020 is not there.

Comment: Please explain the `6 - COUNT(1)` as I fundamentally disagree that this could possibly be the correct formula.

Comment: 6 - count(1) = ( number of years between 2019 and 2022 ) -  [ (billing records for these 3 years) - ( number of years between 2019 and 2022 ) ]

In case of A => 3 - ( 2 - 3 ) =  6 - 2 = 4, For B it will be 6 - 3 = 3.

Comment: But, if a customer has 1 sale in 2019, 1 sale in 2020, and 0 sales in 2021, you get 6-2=4, but is should result in `/3`, not `/4`.

Comment: Similarly, if a customer has 10 sales in 2019, 10 sales in 2020 and 10 sales in 2021, it should be `/30`, but you generate `/3`

Comment: Your argument that the OP is wrong for customer C is actually an argument that shows you've made a mistake. You get (250+300)/4 which makes no sense. The op wants (250+0+300)/3

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the requirements ! @P Mishra Do you confirm what @MatBailie said ?

Comment: @SouhailV - Thanks a ton for taking time to understand and come up with a solution.
Yes, you did get it wrong.  In case of Customer C , AVG will be calculated as
AVG= (250(in 2019) + 300(in 2021) +0(in 2020)) / 3 = 183.3

The Billed_Amount of 2018 = 100 will not be considered since the AVG has to be calculated only between years 2019-2021

Comment: What @MatBailie said is completely right.

Comment: @MatBailie - Thanks a lot for that Solution. It works perfect in this scenario